# TypeInitializationException when linking is enabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ef-core-2.0

I have a Xamarin IOS Application who uses EF Core 2.0.
As long as I'm in Debug mode without SDK Linking, everything works fine. But when I activate SDK Framework Linking (in debug or release mode) I get the following exception when I call this piece of code:

```
var contacts = DbContext.Contacts
                                .Include(x => x.Events)
                                .Include(x => x.Addresses)
                                .Include(x => x.Infos)
                                .ToList();
```

Exception:

```
{System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate) [0x00070] in <773264786149499a986a13db6a7d46fe>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.GetMethod (System.String name, System.Int32 parameterCount, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate) [0x00029] in <0998bf911f014e7884d2695c95a67016>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions..cctor () [0x00000] in <0998bf911f014e7884d2695c95a67016>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at ConnectContacts.DataAccess.Repositories.ContactRepository.DeleteAll () [0x00001] in /Users/npadrutt/Documents/GitHub/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts.DataAccess/Repositories/ContactRepository.cs:43 
  at ConnectContacts.Service.DataServices.ContactDataService+<DeleteAllContacts>d__12.MoveNext () [0x0000f] in /Users/npadrutt/Documents/GitHub/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts.Service/DataServices/ContactDataService.cs:225 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at ConnectContacts.DataAccess.Repositories.ContactRepository.DeleteAll () [0x00001] in /Users/npadrutt/Documents/GitHub/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts.DataAccess/Repositories/ContactRepository.cs:43 
  at ConnectContacts.Service.DataServices.ContactDataService+<DeleteAllContacts>d__12.MoveNext () [0x0000f] in /Users/npadrutt/Documents/GitHub/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts.Service/DataServices/ContactDataService.cs:225 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at ConnectContacts.Business.ViewModels.Wizard.SelectMeContactViewModel+<ImportContacts>d__28.MoveNext () [0x0005d] in /Users/npadrutt/Documents/GitHub/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts.Business/ViewModels/Wizard/SelectMeContactViewModel.cs:129 }
```

Since the exception only occurs when the linking is active, I assume that there is an issue here that something is stripped out what shouldn't.
I already tried with the "--linkskip=" Argument to exclude the EntityFrameworkCore package from linking but that didn't work so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There was a work around in the Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10207#issuecomment-346340935

Comment: I had the same issue, I set my linker settings for my iOS prog to "Dont Link" and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4):

For something a bit cleaner than listing 20 `--linkskip` arguments, you can create a `LinkDescription.xml` file. Add this xml to your iOS project, then add `--xml=${ProjectDir}/LinkDescription.xml` to your mtouch arguments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="mscorlib">
        <type fullname="System.String">
            <method name="Compare"></method>
            <method name="CompareTo"></method>
            <method name="ToUpper"></method>
            <method name="ToLower"></method>
        </type>
    </assembly>
    <assembly fullname="System.Core">
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1"></type>
        <type fullname="System.Linq.Queryable"></type>
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

Sources:

- https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7158#issuecomment-301953071
- https://github.com/JonDouglas/EntityFrameworkWithXamarin/pull/2

Comment: Please consider editing the answer to add a short explanation and an example. Linking to examples is fine, but Stack Overflow prefers self-contained answers.